# printing variable from askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter

whenever i print this

```
def callback():
    file_name = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Music File", "*.mp3"),
                                      ("Video files", "*.mpeg")))
    file_name = file_name.split("/")[-1]
    a = str(file_name)
    return a 

print a

file_name = Button(root, text="open", command=callback)
file_name.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
```

the output will be like this

```
.35430920L
```

but when i use global, it does print out the file name which i want

```
def callback():
    global a
    file_name = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Music File", "*.mp3"),
                                      ("Video files", "*.mpeg")))
    file_name = file_name.split("/")[-1]
    a = str(file_name)
    print a

file_name = Button(root, text="open", command=callback)
file_name.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
```

the output will be like this

```
"example.mp3"
```

Comment: BTW, do not use `filename.split("/")[-1]`, instead do `from os.path import basename`; `file_name = basename(file_name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output happens in execution order. In your first example, the variable `a` is given the value `.35430920L` before the `print a`  runs, and chronologically the `print` statement occurs before the file dialog is actually even opened, thus it is impossible to print the value of chosen file there.

In the latter case, being in the callback function, the result is already known. Notice that you do not even need a global variable for that case. (you can remove the `global a`, unless you need the result outside of that function).

Tkinter uses event-driven programming paradigm, it calls callback functions for each occurring event. What you want to do for any larger program, is to wrap your application and widgets in a class, and store things like filenames in class attributes.

Comment: Basically yes ;) though tabs not for indentation but spaces; and even if `print a` was indented, the `return` would have ended execution before the end of func (though returns from tkinter callbacks do make little sense.